# Facebook Canvas Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

What is the best way to login to a Facebook Canvas app? All the tutorials I see show a user needing to press a login button which seems odd since the users is already logged into Facebook. Other apps that I have seen on Facebook show a "Go To App" button. What is the process to get that dialog to show up with extended permissions? Is the oAuth Url redirection the best way to give my app access to the users information?

Comment: if your app doesn't have a non-user welcome page (landing page), then you can redirect non-users directly to the oauth page then back to the canvas page.

Comment: BTW Facebook is removing [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went the PHP route and it seems to be working great.

```
$user = null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once 'fb-php/src/facebook.php';
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR APP ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR SECRET ID',
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'email,publish_stream,user_photos'
        )
);

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
    d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just digging into this stuff for the first time this week, so its likely I'm not doing things the best way yet, but here's how I've been doing it in my sandbox:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  login();
});

var login = function(){
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     get_fb_info();
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'user_about_me, friends_about_me, user_activities, friends_activities, user_birthday, friends_birthday, user_checkins, friends_checkins, user_education_history, friends_education_history, user_events, friends_events, user_groups, friends_groups, user_hometown, friends_hometown, user_interests, friends_interests, user_likes, friends_likes, user_location, friends_location, user_notes, friends_notes, user_photos, friends_photos, user_questions, friends_questions, user_relationships, friends_relationships, user_relationship_details, friends_relationship_details, user_religion_politics, friends_religion_politics, user_status, friends_status, user_subscriptions, friends_subscriptions, user_videos, friends_videos, user_website, friends_website, user_work_history, friends_work_history, email, read_friendlists, read_insights, read_mailbox, read_requests, read_stream, xmpp_login, ads_management, create_event, manage_friendlists, manage_notifications, user_online_presence, friends_online_presence, publish_checkins, publish_stream, rsvp_event, publish_actions, user_actions.music, friends_actions.music, user_actions.news, friends_actions.news, user_actions.video, friends_actions.video, user_actions:ssiz-three, friends_actions:ssiz-three, user_games_activity, friends_games_activity, manage_pages'});
}
```

I'd also love to hear what the "best" way to do this is.  I've also played with `fb:login-button` but for some reason I couldn't get that to work correctly.

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1" scope="user_about_me...">
</fb:login-button>
```